# Embedding reStructuredText in Python docstrings

Tags: python, vim, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'd like to see some nice syntax highlighting and colouring in my Python's docstrings which (of course) are valid RESt. For example:

```
'''
A section
=========

an example::

    some code
'''
rest of python code
```

The closest I've got is this in my `.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`:

```
syn include syntax/rst.vim 
syn region pythonDocstring  start=+^\s*'''+ end=+'''+ contained
```

According to [the documentation of syntax-include](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-include) that should be sufficient to. Also note that `rst.vim` re-defines a bunch of python entities so I've had to comment out all sections related to code:

```
" syn region rstCodeBlock contained matchgroup=rstDirective
"       \ start=+\%(sourcecode\|code\%(-block\)\=\)::\_s*\n\ze\z(\s\+\)+
"       \ skip=+^$+
"       \ end=+^\z1\@!+
"       \ contains=@NoSpell
" syn cluster rstDirectives add=rstCodeBlock

" if !exists('g:rst_syntax_code_list')
[...]
```

Lastly, I can't use `!runtime` because `rst.vim` does nothing if the `b:current_syntax` variable is already defined:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif
```

Despite my efforts my docstring stays the same colour as other comments, with no syntax highlighting.

I've tried also this:

```
syn region pythonDocstring  start=+^\s*'''+ end=+'''+ contains=CONTAINED
```

But I only managed to change the colour of the block to be `Special` rather than `Comment`.

Perhaps I should define the pythonDocstring not to have any default colouring?

Further note: if I remove references to python raw strings in python.vim, colouring disappears but I only get the python keywords highlighted.

---

## Update

Trying one of the solutions below with my after/syntax/python.vim file:

```
syn include @pythonRst syntax/rst.vim 
syn region pythonDocstring  start=+^\s*'''+ end=+'''+ contains=@pythonRst
```

Resulted in the RESt file being grayed out when opening a file with `.py` extension:

[image: python syntax]

While opening the same file with a `.rst`. extension seems to work fine (just to show that I have a rest syntax file):

[image: rest syntax]

Note that I've tried both with and without `colorscheme` in my .vimrc

Answer (score 3):

As the reST syntax should only be applied *inside* Python doc strings, you have to include them into a syntax cluster (here: `@pythonRst`). Otherwise, Vim would try to match them everywhere.

```
syn include @pythonRst syntax/rst.vim
```

Then, define a region covering those doc strings, and explicitly instruct Vim to highlight reST syntax in there (via `contains=`)

```
syn region pythonDocstring  start=+^\s*'''+ end=+'''+ contains=@pythonRst
```

Comment: I had tried that but it does not seem to do the trick. I'll post a few pictures as an update.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally managed to crack it.

Firstly I copied the `rst.vim` file from $VIMRUNTIME/syntax into my `.vim/syntax/` folder

Secondly, this is my `.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` file (thanks @Ingo):

```
syn include @pythonRst syntax/rst.vim 
syn region pythonDocstring  start=+^\s*"""+ end=+"""+ contains=@pythonRst
```

Thirdly I edited the file and **commented out** this block to ignore whether current syntax is set:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif
```

This block to load code plugins (it was causing some recursive problem because it was trying to load a python syntax file, which loaded this syntax file:

```
for code in g:rst_syntax_code_list
    unlet! b:current_syntax
[...]
   unlet! prior_isk
endfor
```

And finally this block at the end:

```
let b:current_syntax = "rst"
```

So that the syntax would stay as python.

Result:

[image: success!]